# Domain Access Module not working for second domain?

Tags: 8, multi-sites, domain-access, subsites

I have installed the Drupal on Main Domain and install the module **Domain Access**. Under the setting of Domain I have setup the other domain where I want to use .

```
EX: example.com
Ex: example.com.au
```

For First domain it's working fine but after setup other domain it's not working . I have added the domain with godaddy account and it created the sub directory with the **example.com.au**  .

Step by setup:

1. Install Drupal Primary Domain.Example.com
2. Add the subdomain example.com.au
3. Install the Domain Access Module
4. Configure the Domain Under Setting of Module

[image]

It's showing error message during active other domain

```
The server request to http://example.com.au/ returned a 500 response. To proceed, disable the Test server response in the form.
```

After uncheck "Test Server Response" able to add the other domain.

Comment: What subdirectory, where? You must change the second domain's DNS settings to point to the same folder as the first domain. Alternatively, if I understand it right, `/var/www/example.com.au` must be a symlink to `/var/www/example.com`.

Comment: after create subdomain example.com.au its create the directory in the root folder . should i follow the step of multi site setup and than use the domain access module?

Comment: can you suggest me any tutorial for using domain access module in drupal 8?

Comment: 1. No 2. That would make this question off-topic. As you can simply use Google to find any possible off-site resource yourself.